# Perl sigdie handler and eval

Tags: perl, eval, log4perl

I am overriding my SIG die handler as below inside my Logger module.

```
# Catch die messages and log them with logdie
$SIG{__DIE__} = \&logdie;
```

Now below program run as expected and post processing will be called.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path;
# use MyLogger;

my $dir="/random";
eval {
  # local $SIG{__DIE__};
  File::Path::make_path($dir);
};
if($@) {
 warn("Cannot create $dir :$@ \n");
}
print "Post processing \n";
```

However, if i include my logger module and add `use MyLogger` the code fails inside `eval` statment with below error and post processing is not called.

[ERROR] 2015/04/27 22:19:07 Carp.pm:166> mkdir /random: Permission denied at ./test.pl line 11.

One option to fix this to add a local sigdie handle (as shown in commented code).

However, my logger module is used by many scripts.

Is there a way to modify my Logger module so that it supresses ERROR message when called from inside eval block ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`$^S`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#EXCEPTIONS_BEING_CAUGHT) indicates whether the current execution point is inside of an `eval` block:

```
$^S         State
---------   -------------------------------------
undef       Parsing module, eval, or main program
true (1)    Executing an eval
false (0)   Otherwise
```

So it sounds like you want to check whether `$^S` is true at the beginning of your `__DIE__` handler:

```
package MyLogger;
sub logdie {
    $^S && die $_[0];    # use default die handler
    ...                  # else use custom die handler
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i added `return if (!defined($^S) or $^S);`  to sigdie handler in MyLogger and its works perfectly.